# Simple AHK script or .bat file to change power plan, disable windows aero, and disable desktop icons

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

I haven't done much scripting in AHK (mostly just "sendinput" stuff), so any help would be greatly appreciated :D

So, the script or .bat file would need to:

- Change to a specific power plan
- Disable Windows Aero
- Disable desktop icons
- Exit itself

Thank you again :)

Comment: A few of these are registry settings, I would look into the methods for modifying reg keys using VBS. You might also want to look into scripting GPO updates.

Comment: Power plan can be changed with [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=68530).

Answer (score 1):

This should put you on the right track.

```
; Disable Aero
RunWait, %comspec% /c "net stop uxsms",, Hide

; Run powercfg.exe -list in command line to get the correct guid
RunWait, %comspec% /c "powercfg.exe /setactive 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c",, Hide

; Hide icons (might require log off/in)
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, HideIcons, 1

ExitApp
```

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, I completely forgot about the question.  

I was unable to get any of those lines to work, on their own or together, not sure why. Are they computer specific? Or are they isolated code? I don't know enough about code to recognise whether they are or not

Comment: The first command should work no problem.  The second, you can verify the correct `setactive` by opening a command prompt and typing `powercfg -list`. Are you sure it is running at all?